# How prove this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^ae^{-nx^2}$ Uniform convergence on $(0,+\infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $a>2$,show that: the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^ae^{-nx^2}$$

Uniform convergence on $(0,+\infty)$

My try:
case 1:$x>1$

since 
$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$
for every fix $a>2$,then exsit $\beta>a>2$
$$x^ae^{-nx^2}=\dfrac{x^a}{1+nx+\dfrac{(nx)^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{(nx)^{\beta}}{\beta!}+\cdots}\le\dfrac{\beta!}{n^{\beta}}x^{a-\beta}\le\dfrac{\beta!}{n^{\beta}},x>1$$

But for $0<x\le 1$,I can't.

maybe this problem have other nice methods.Thank you

Comment: The exponentials terms are in geometric progression. Then their sum write 1 / (Exp[x^2] - 1). Can this help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let
$$f_n(x)=x^a e^{-nx^2}$$
then
$$f'_n(x)=x^{a-1}(a-2nx^2)e^{-nx^2}=0\iff x=0\;\text{or}\; x_n=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt{2n}}\;\text{on}\; (0,+\infty)$$
and we verify easily that $f_n$ has a maximum at $x_n$ and 
$$||f_n||_\infty=f_n(x_n)\sim_\infty  \frac{C}{n^{a/2}}$$
hence the series $\displaystyle \sum_n ||f_n||_\infty$ is convergent by asymptotic comparison with a convergent Riemann series (since $a/2>1$) hence $\displaystyle \sum_n f_n$ is a [normal series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence) hence it's uniformly convergent series.

Comment: Very nice Sami. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Use Weierstrass's criterion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test.

Ans also for every $x>0$ there is a $n_o\in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac {1}{n_0}<x\iff \frac {n}{n^2_0}<nx^2$ $$\iff \frac {1}{e^{nx^2}} <\frac {1}{e^{\frac {n}{n^2_0}}}$$

and $$\sum_{k=n^2_0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{e^{\frac {n}{n^2_0}}}<+\infty$$ from the root criterion.